# What is python alternate to war file in java?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Today we just tried to create a war file in python but did not get any solutions.

Could you let me know why python is not supporting to create a war kind of file.

Is this because python does not support web applications but django framework does? then is there a way to create WAR file using django?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to deploy a Django site on something like Tomcat?

Comment: Yes I am trying to deploy a django project on Apache httpd

Comment: There is full documentation on the Django site about how to deploy with Apache. There is no need at all to create a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using [webpy](http://webpy.org/) for the python webserver, and then compile the whole project with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), for a single deployable, executable file on target system.

Comment: We dont have permission to install anything on production server so it wont require any installation on production server right? We can create an executable in our local and then execute it in production and no need to install anything on end server, am I correct?

Comment: PyInstaller creates a single executable, that the target system runs.  We compile with PyInstaller on a development machine, than move the resulting executable to the production/target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Django-Jython: https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/

It is a collection of tools and database backends to use the Django web framework on top of Jython (Java Python).